# Не заменяется строка

Tags: php, строки

Добрый день!
Такой вопрос не работает почему-то `str_replace`.
Посмотрите, в чем ошибка, поскольку я нуб в пхп. Вот код:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("parcer_test.html","r+");

$allowable = "<br>";
$str = "Пришлите весёлое стихотворение!";

while (!feof($handle))
{
    $text = file_get_contents("parcer_test.html");
    str_replace($str,$allowable,$text);
    file_put_contents("parcer_test.html",$text);

    print fgetss($handle, 2048,$allowable);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, `str_replace` работает! Но вы его не используете!

Нужно отдать результат функции в переменную!

```
$text = str_replace($str,$allowable,$text);
```

А не просто

```
str_replace($str,$allowable,$text);
```

И дальше работать с `$text`

Comment: спасибо, но так тоже не работает( я уже попробывал

Comment: Есть ошибки? Что именно не работает? Запись? Замена?
Зачем вам while?

$FileAdrToOpen = './file.html';
$File = (is_file($FileAdrToOpen)) ? file_get_contents($FileAdrToOpen) : false;

if($File) {

$Zamenyt = array('one','two');
$ZamenytNa = array('1','2');

$NewFileData = str_replace($Zamenyt,$ZamenytNa,$File);

if(file_put_contents($FileAdrToOpen, $NewFileData)) {
echo 'ok';
} else echo 'bad!';

}


Пробуйте так

Comment: в том то и дело что ошибок phpStorm не показывает, а строка как была так и осталась на месте

Comment: а while нужен для того чтобы все теги убрать из документа, поскольку мне нужно от туда только текст выцепить

Comment: А ошибки не в phpStorm(е)? А в браузере после выполнения?
И теги можно убрать без цикла - strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

Вы не принимаете значение которое возврщает функция

> `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`
>
> Эта функция возвращает строку или массив, в котором все вхождения search в subject заменены на replace.

И вообще вы понимаете что Вы делаете? Если вы хотите заменить во всем файле достаточно сделать так

1.html

```
<br>
123
<br>
123
```

Далее этот код

`file_put_contents("1.html",str_replace("<br>", "", file_get_contents("1.html")));`

убирает из файла все вхождения <br> и записывает обратно.

Comment: мне нужно убрать строку и заменить ее на <br>

Comment: @Uchiha1992, Тоже самое  `... str_replace("строка", "<br>", ... )